# Access call log

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I get access to the call log in windows phone 8 actually I want to make a call log which will store all the log even if it has been deleted from the call history

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Would you mind just adding the tag of version of the language **you're actually working in**, rather than just all of them? If you're not at the point of being able to pick one, you're most likely not at the point of asking an (appropriate) [so] question either.

Comment: Yes, please retag the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that API is not publicly available for you to use due to the security concerns. OEM and partners can get access to such restricted and non-public API, but developers currently cannot.

You can and you should vote for that feature on the User Voice page: [Please - allow readonly access to Call History and Text History](http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1905841-please-allow-readonly-access-to-call-history-and).

Answer (score 0):

Save the out going calls in your sqlite table.
just add the sqlite extension for windows phone 8 if not exist then create a class that will hold the number dialed and its date....

create a new page(phone page) that will display your logs
done...